# complexity of modal logic axioms

Tags: complexity-theory, logic, space-complexity, propositional-logic, modal-logic

I am writing a paper in which I want to include complexity results for different modal logics and possibly add a reference to a specific paper.

At the moment I have the following:

K- no restrictions on the frame, NPComplete

T- reflexive, NPComplete

K4- transitive, PSpaceComplete

S4 and S4.3 also PSpaceComplete

S5- symmetric, transitive and reflexive, NPComplete.

**I am not able to find any results regarding complexity of the following axioms for modal logic:**

D- serial

KB- symmetric

B- reflexive, symmetric

**The above 3 modal logics are important for me and I really need the complexity results with a specific paper. If anyone could help me out here it would be great thanks.**

Answer (score 3):

You might find interesting some of the results in [On the Complexity of Fragments of Modal Logics](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~nguyen/cmd2.pdf) by Linh Anh Nguyen (in Advances in Modal Logic, 2004: 249-268). A version of the paper is available in the home page of Nyugen.

And probably you are already familiar with [A guide to completeness and complexity of modal logics](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/halpern/papers/guide.ps) by Joseph Y. Halpern and Yoram Moses (in Artificial Intelligence 54, 1992, pp. 319-379). A version of the paper similar to the published version is available in postscript and pdf in the home page of Halpern.